# Marking a state as consumed without changing its contents in Corda

Tags: java, blockchain, rpc, corda

I am working on a simple use case in which I need to take a state as an input in a transaction and generate a new output state. But I want the contents of the state to be the same. I just want to mark the input state as consumed and generate a new output state with the same contents. The Cordapp I am writing is in Java.

How can i do that in Corda?

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you need to perform three steps:

1. Retrieve the input state you want to consume
2. Make an output state that's a copy of the input state
3. Add them both to the transaction builder

Here's an example of doing this for a state representing an obligation:

```
// Retrieve the state using its linear ID.
QueryCriteria queryCriteria = new QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(
        null,
        ImmutableList.of(linearId),
        Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED,
        null);

List<StateAndRef<Obligation>> obligations = getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(Obligation.class, queryCriteria).getStates();
if (obligations.size() != 1) {
    throw new FlowException(String.format("Obligation with id %s not found.", linearId));
}
StateAndRef<Obligation> inputStateAndRef = obligations.get(0);
Obligation input = inputStateAndRef.getState().getData();

// Create the new output state.
Obligation output = new Obligation(input.getAmount(), input.getLender(), input.getBorrower(), input.getPaid(), input.getLinearId());

// Creating the transaction builder (don't forget to add a command!)
final TransactionBuilder builder = new TransactionBuilder(notary)
        .addInputState(inputStateAndRef)
        .addOutputState(output, OBLIGATION_CONTRACT_ID);
```

Comment: Is there still some meta data that changes underneath that identifies that the state has changed? Like a timestamp or a ref of some kind?