# Can a Corda transaction eliminate a state with no output?

Tags: corda

In Corda, is there any method to eliminate (or consume) input state in a transaction by not adding output one?

The aim is to mark a state as consumed and let it not available to use anymore.

P.S. Not like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52361888/marking-a-state-as-consumed-without-changing-its-contents-in-corda) mention, because it's output state is available in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can try to create a Transaction builder without an output state, something like below:

```
final TransactionBuilder builder = new TransactionBuilder(notary)
        .addInputState(inputStateAndRef);
```